# Access location property in App component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to access the props from react router in my App component? I am trying to access the `this.props.location` property from the `BrowserRouter` in `App.js` so that I can pass it into `HeaderContainer`.

**index.js**

```
function renderApp() {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>,
        document.getElementById('react-app')
    );
}
renderApp();
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <HeaderContainer />
                <Main />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just get it from this.props.location.pathname?

Comment: whats wrong with `this.props.location`? this should work https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

Comment: `this.props.location` is undefined because it's not inside a `Route`. I need to access the location from with in the `HeaderContainer`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `withRouter` HOC.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return (
      <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>
    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(ShowTheLocation)
```

Reference:https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter